# Fatal Error while transition

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewanimationtransition

> Error : "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" during transition between two view on same view controller

When I call `Flip1` function it gives me above error.

Code Below :

```
@IBAction func Flip(_ sender: AnyObject){
    UIView.transition(from: Back, to: Front, duration: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromLeft, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func Flip1(_ sender: AnyObject){
    UIView.transition(from: Front, to: Back, duration: 1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.transitionFlipFromRight, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Either back or front view must be nil.You are using those from storyboard or what?

Comment: @GarimaSaini yes storyboard

Comment: Have you checked that your outlets `Front`and `Back` are assigned in the storyboard?

Comment: @macmoonshine yes they are assigned

Comment: @ShikhaSharma - Check on transition your Back and Front should not be nil.

Comment: Debug step by step and check if both the views are coming nil and try to unbind and then again bind those outlets.

Comment: @GarimaSaini front is nil when i call flip again after calling flip 1

Comment: unbind it from storyboard and bind it again.See if works.

Comment: @GarimaSaini but it is showing when i call "flip" for the first time

Comment: Front is not nil when Flip() is called but when Flip1()  is called by the time, it becomes nil.

 check whether there are any methods that use Front view and check any of those are deallocating Front view.

Comment: Are both of these views in the same controller or are you doing this in a segue?

Comment: create a strong reference,that would do..because a weak reference with UIView.transition method can probably deallocate the view after transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah I found the mistake finally.

Just make the outlet as strong reference instead or weak like:

```
@IBOutlet var Front: UIView!
@IBOutlet var Back: UIView!
```

and it is done!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer to your problem: [transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622562-transitionfromview?language=objc)

> Parameters (According to Documentation):
>
> **fromView** 
> The starting view for the transition. By default, this view is **removed from its superview** as part of the transition.
>
> **toView** 
> The ending view for the transition. By default, this view is **added to the superview** of fromView as part of the transition.

**Solution to your problem:**

Use [transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transitionwithview) instead of [transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622562-transitionfromview?language=objc) if you want both views in memory.

Try this:

1. Add a UIView containing both 'Front' and 'Back' view. (Add a new view as a super view of both 'Front' and 'Back' view)
2. Perform flip animation on 'super view' along with hide and unhide operations on 'Front' and 'Back' views. with [transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transitionwithview) animation block

Sample code:

```
@IBOutlet var superView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var Back: UIView!
@IBOutlet var Front: UIView!

@IBAction func Flip(_ sender: AnyObject){

    self.Front.isHidden = false
    self.Front.alpha = 0.1
    UIView.transition(with: superView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromLeft, animations: {
        self.Back.alpha = 0.1
        self.Front.alpha = 1.0
    }) { (isCompleted) in
        self.Back.isHidden = true
    }
}

@IBAction func Flip1(_ sender: AnyObject){

    self.Back.isHidden = false
    self.Back.alpha = 0.1
    UIView.transition(with: superView, duration: 0.5, options: .transitionFlipFromRight, animations: {
        self.Front.alpha = 0.1
        self.Back.alpha = 1.0
    }) { (isCompleted) in
        self.Front.isHidden = true
    }
}
```